# Appending same node in different windows

Tags: javascript, html, append, new-window

I want to append an object, that was created in a parent window to a child window:

```
div = document.createElement( "div" );
document.body.appendChild( div );
// Here come div's atts;
render = window.open().document;
render.body.appendChild( div );
```

but the new DIV is appended only to the child window. If I comment the last line - the div is appended to the parent window. Can that be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing since I misread the question:

```
newelement = element.cloneNode(true); // true to clone children too
```

Still there is no html or body in the new window that it can be appended to. At least not in chrome.

Try this instead:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        div = document.createElement( "div" );
        // add some text to know if it's really there
        div.innerText = 'text of the div';
        document.body.appendChild( div );
        // Here come div's atts;
        render = window.open().document;
        // create the body of the new document
        render.write('<html><body></body></html>');
        // now you can append the div
        render.body.appendChild( div );
        alert(render.body.innerHTML);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, read carefully... The div is appended first to the parent window, but then immediately appended to the child window. You even can see the "jump"

Comment: Yeah, I see... you need to clone it... same as always with javascript. You're changing the object.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a copy of that div and then appending that to the child instead of the original div?

**Edit:** Okay, then yeah, that would be the cloneNode function.

```
clone = div.cloneNode(true);
render = window.open().document;
render.body.appendChild(clone);
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Is there a function (Not jQuery) to clone elements? The problem is that I need exactly the same node tree in both windows.